# How to add noise in the mice polyreg implementation

Tags: r, r-mice

In MICE R `mice.impute.polyreg.r` (imputation for categorical response variables by the Bayesian polytomous regression model), it is mentioned  that the method consists of the following steps:

1. Fit categorical response as a multinomial model
2. Compute predicted categories
3. Add appropriate noise to predictions.

In the implementation:

```
mice.impute.polyreg <- function(y, ry, x, nnet.maxit = 100, 
                                nnet.trace = FALSE, nnet.maxNWts = 1500, ...) {

    x <- as.matrix(x)
    aug <- augment(y, ry, x, ...)
    x <- aug$x
    y <- aug$y
    ry <- aug$ry
    w <- aug$w

    fy <- as.factor(y)
    nc <- length(levels(fy))
    un <- rep(runif(sum(!ry)), each = nc)


    xy <- cbind.data.frame(y = y, x = x)  # fixed SvB 6/12/2010

    if (ncol(x) == 0L) 
        xy <- data.frame(xy, int = 1)
    fit <- multinom(formula(xy), data = xy[ry,,drop = FALSE ], 
                    weights = w[ry], maxit = nnet.maxit, trace = nnet.trace, 
                    maxNWts = nnet.maxNWts, ...)
    post <- predict(fit, xy[!ry, ], type = "probs")
    if (sum(!ry) == 1) 
        post <- matrix(post, nrow = 1, ncol = length(post))  

    if (is.vector(post)) 
        post <- matrix(c(1 - post, post), ncol = 2)
    draws <- un > apply(post, 1, cumsum)
    idx <- 1 + apply(draws, 2, sum)

    return(levels(fy)[idx])
}
```

[link to github code](https://github.com/stefvanbuuren/mice/blob/4b2ffdf3e41aed284d9990add29e89f05bc6ab39/R/mice.impute.polyreg.r)

I am able to make out the first two steps, however I can't seem to find where in the implementation "noise" has been added to the predictions. It seems that the predicted categories are returned directly as they are.

Am I missing something?